# MsAdalAngular6Module giving error after angular version up gradation from 15 to 17 version in Angular

Tags: angular-errorhandler

Please find the below error, which am getting at runtime (npm start). This error is getting after upgrading the angular application from 15 to 17 version.

Error :-
**error NG6005: MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument.Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type. If this occurrence is in library code you don't control, please contact the library authors.**

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuZ06.png)
[app.modules.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7lcN.png)

application should run without exception, and we tried with many ways by updating the code. But we didn't get solution on this.